# MySQL Partitioning Error

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm running MySQL 5.6 and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `rawdata` (
  `RawDataSeq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SpeciesSeq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DataSourceSeq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MeasurementSeq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecordingDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawSensorData` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawDataNumeric` decimal(36,18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawDataString` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawDataDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawDataTime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RawDataDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ActiveRecord` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastUpdateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BadData` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RawDataSeq`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5676258 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I'm trying to partition the table by 'RecordingDateTime' using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE rawdata PARTITION BY RANGE (RecordingDateTime) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01 00:00:00')),
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I'm receiving the following error message:

*Query: ALTER TABLE rawdata PARTITION BY RANGE (RecordingDateTime) ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2013), PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN...
Error Code: 1659
Field 'RecordingDateTime' is of a not allowed type for this type of partitioning*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
PRIMARY KEY (`RawDataSeq`, RecordingDateTime)

ALTER TABLE rawdata PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(RecordingDateTime)) (
  PARTITION p_old  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2013-01-01')),
  PARTITION p2013  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2014-01-01')),
  PARTITION p2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-01-01')),
  PARTITION p2015  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-01-01')),
  PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

The code you need each December is found [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: This is fantastic and worked seamlessly.  Thank you!! I also checked out your post regarding partition maintenance and in December, can I simply drop all my partitions and add an additional one for 2016?

Comment: Caution:  `DROP PARTITION` will lose any data in the partition.  `REORGANIZE PARTITION` can be used to combine (or split) partition(s).  There is rarely any use for less than, say, 10 partitions.  An there can be performance issues with more than, say, 50 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a problem with the `datetime` value and the integer values you are using.  One method is:

```
ALTER TABLE rawdata PARTITION BY RANGE (year(RecordingDateTime)) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

If you don't store the `RecordingDateTime` as a timestamp, you can also try:

```
ALTER TABLE rawdata PARTITION BY RANGE (year(RecordingDateTime)*100 + month(RecordDateTime) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (201300),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (201400),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (201500),
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (201506),
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Otherwise, store the value as a `timestamp` and use timestamp ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried the second option your provided since I don't store the values as a timestamp.  I now receive the error message: Error Code: 1503
A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function